# Python API calling+ for loops

Tags: python, api, for-loop

Hi I am trying to call API and get a growth rate of poke API. I am sort of stuck now and `return experience += 1` part gives me syntax error as well. Can you drop me a hint? Or how I should approach?

I intended to get each level & experience level from the first function then calculate the growth rate at the second function, the first part works but I got stuck at the second part.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def get_growth_rate(rate):
    request1=requests.get(rate)
    loaded1= json.loads(request1.content)

    try:
        descriptions,formula,id_1,levels,name,pokemon_species = loaded1.values()
        return levels

    except IndexError:
        return None
        pass
    
def plot_growth_rate(levels):
    experience=[]
    levels[0],levels[1] = get_growth_rate(rate)
    for i in level[0]:
        return experience += 1
                
    growth_rate = (experience[i+1]-experience[i]/experience[i])) * 100
    get_growth_rate("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/growth-rate/5")
```

Comment: Please post the full error

Comment: You can't return experience += 1. Because it is indeed invalid syntax

Comment: The code is not clear and contains multiple syntax issuse.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `return experience += 1` *should do*?

Answer (score 2):

`return experience += 1` is syntactically incorrect, as it said. To do it, you need two lines:

```
experience += 1
return experience
```

Or if the `experience` is a local variable and you don't need to use it after the function returned, it is `return experience + 1`.

The loop with `return` without any conditions doesn't make any sense.